# Issues with variable dimensioning with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables, dimension

I have a code in VBA which runs a model. I am going to omit the body of the code and show the code which i believe is where the issue arises. Please let me know if you would like to see the full script.

The issues is when I run the code, I receive a run time error. I am under the impression that this is because the variable type does not allow the code to be executed.

Below is is the how the variables are dimensioned and the value they are assigned.

```
Dim VOL(10) As Double         'Variable for Reservoir Volume
Dim QOUT(10) As Double         'Variable for Reservoir Release
Dim DK(10) As Integer         'Variable for Kinetic Coefficient
Dim Alpha As Double         'Variable for AL in Function
Alpha = (QOUT(I5) / VOL(I5)) + DK(I5)
Function RHS(TERM1 As Double, Y As Double, Alpha As Double)     'The RHS of the differential equation
RHS = TERM1 - Y * Alpha
```

The below is the code for the I5 Loop.

```
For I5 = 1 To NREACT
        WLUP(I5) = 0
        If I5 = 1 Then GoTo RungeKutta
        WLUP(I5) = CONCUP(I5 - 1) * QOUT(I5 - 1)
```

RungeKutta:

```
        Alpha = (QOUT(I5) / VOL(I5)) + DK(I5)
```

The Values for QOUT, VOL, and DK are as follows: 1250, 35000, and 0 respectively.

I have tried trouble shooting by assigning QOUT, VOL, and DK as different variable types but to no avail still receive the same run time error for the Alpha equation. The error is "Ru-time error '6': Overflow.

Comment: `The Values for QOUT, VOL, and DK are as follows: 1250, 35000, and 0 respectively.` - how can arrays have single values each? `(QOUT(I5) / VOL(I5)) + DK(I5)` - what is `I5`? And most importantly, what is the error?

Comment: @Gserg There is more to the script but essentially those variables are assigned an array because it loops through that array of which there are ten potential initial values.

Comment: @Gserg in this case those are the initial values for the first loop. I5 is in reference to the 5th loop in the script.

Comment: @omegastripes I ammended the question to show you the I5 loop, at least the beginning of it.

Comment: "Run-time error '6': Overflow" is caused by `VOL(I5)` is 0. Choose Debug in the error dialog and check Locals window.

Comment: Note `Dim VOL(10)` declares array of 11 elements, arrays are zero-based by default.

Comment: @omegastripes, I was able to solve the issue. The code pulls the number of data sets available to loop through of which there are ten but, only one of my sets of data is complete. However, the cell for which the amount of data sets the code runs through was set to three which do not have any values in them. 

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!